# Problema con Dockerfile y jenkins

Tags: java, docker, jenkins

Estoy empezando con los dockerfile y jenkinsfiles y estoy bastante perdido. No se exactamente cual es el problema. Estoy tratando de crear imágenes más pequeñas.

Este es mi Jenkinsfile

```
node {
   // -- Configura variables
   echo 'Configurando variables'
   def mvnHome = tool 'M3'
   env.PATH = "${mvnHome}/bin:${env.PATH}"
   echo "var mvnHome='${mvnHome}'"
   echo "var env.PATH='${env.PATH}'"

   // -- Descarga código desde SCM
   echo 'Descargando código de SCM'
   sh 'rm -rf *'
   checkout scm
   stage('Package') {
       dir('PruebaDockerSVN') {
            sh 'mvn clean package -DskipTests'
       }
   }

   stage('Create Docker Image') {
       dir('PruebaDockerSVN') {
           docker.build("prueba-docker-svn")
       }
   }

   stage ('Run Application') {
       dir('PruebaDockerSVN') {
           try { 
               sh "docker run -it --rm --volume 
               "$PWD"/pom.xml://usr/src/app/pom.xml 
               \ --volume "$HOME"/.m2:/root/.m2 maven:3-jdk-8-alpine mvn 
               install"


           } catch (error) {
           } finally {}
        }
   }
}
```

Mi Dockerfile es este

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
# ----
# Install Maven
RUN apk add --no-cache curl tar bash
ARG MAVEN_VERSION=3.3.9
ARG USER_HOME_DIR="/root"
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/maven && \
curl -fsSL http://apache.osuosl.org/maven/maven- 
3/$MAVEN_VERSION/binaries/apache-maven-$MAVEN_VERSION-bin.tar.gz | tar - 
xzC 
/usr/share/maven --strip-components=1 && \
ln -s /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn
ENV MAVEN_HOME /usr/share/maven
ENV MAVEN_CONFIG "$USER_HOME_DIR/.m2"
# speed up Maven JVM a bit
ENV MAVEN_OPTS="-XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1"
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/mvn"]

WORKDIR /app

# Add POM and source
ADD pom.xml /app/pom.xml
ADD src /app/src

# Build the app
RUN ["mvn", "clean", "package"]

# Run the app
RUN bash -c 'touch /app/target/pruebasvn-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","- 
jar","/app/target/pruebasvn-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Al ejecutar mi Job en jenkins este es el error que me da

```
[Pipeline] { (Create Docker Image)
[Pipeline] dir
Running in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/prueba-docker-svn/PruebaDockerSVN
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[PruebaDockerSVN] Running shell script
+ docker build -t prueba-docker-svn .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 19.44 MB

Error response from daemon: Unknown instruction: /USR/SHARE/MAVEN
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

**EDITADO**: esto se solucionó como decía @César.

Ahora mi problema es otro. He tenido que cambiar el Dockerfile para que coja el jdk en lugar del jre porque me daba errores, en el pom he tenido que meter esto, porque ejecutaba unas pruebas y daba error.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Sigue dando error pero al menos continúa... Ahora mi único problema es que me crea la imagen pero no crea el contenedor. Si pongo en la consola docker run -d -p 8585:8080 prueba-docker-svn la aplicación funciona perfectamente.

así que en el Jenkinsfile justo debajo de 
    sh "docker run -it --rm --volume 
               "$PWD"/pom.xml://usr/src/app/pom.xml \ 
    --volume "$HOME"/.m2:/root/.m2 maven:3-jdk-8-alpine mvn install"

he puesto:
    sh "docker run -d -p 8585:8080 prueba-docker-svn"

pero no lo está haciendo. No se si el problema viene de esta salida de jenkins cuando termina

```
[Pipeline] { (Run Application)
[Pipeline] dir
Running in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/prueba-docker-svn/PruebaDockerSVN
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[PruebaDockerSVN] Running shell script
+ docker run -it --rm --volume
flag needs an argument: --volume
See 'docker run --help'.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Supongo que cuando dices que haces un `docker run -d -p 8585:8080 prueba-docker-svn` lo ejecutas con el usuario jenkins ¿verdad?

Comment: Si, lo que he podido ir viendo es que no me ejecutaba ese comando por el error que me da en flag needs an argument: --volume. También vi que no existía la ruta usr/src/app/. Cambié el dockerfile para que la crease y pusiese ahi el pom pero el comando este  sh "docker run -it --rm --volume 
               "$PWD"/pom.xml://usr/src/app/pom.xml 
               \ --volume "$HOME"/.m2:/root/.m2 maven:3-jdk-8-alpine mvn nunca me ha llegado a funcionar. Si me olvido de los volúmenes y pongo simplemente docker run -d -p 8585:8080 prueba-docker-svn funciona bien.

Answer (score 2):

Parece ser que tienes saltos de línea en tu Dockerfile, especificamente en la parte del primer `RUN` después del comando `tar`. Debería ser:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

# ...

RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/maven && \
  curl -fsSL http://apache.osuosl.org/maven/maven-3/$MAVEN_VERSION/binaries/apache-maven-$MAVEN_VERSION-bin.tar.gz | tar - xzC /usr/share/maven --strip-components=1 && \
  ln -s /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn

# ...
```

Comment: Pues si, muchas gracias, eso era.